# Programmatically created UIScrollView won't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

Hi I'm creating a UIScrollView with code only and I'm using auto layout. Currently I don't have any constraints set on it. But I have tried putting constraints on it. Everywhere I've looked it has the same exact code as me so I can't figure out why its not working. (I have it set as blue just so I could make sure it wasn't showing up).

Thanks!

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 800);
_scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
```

Comment: Wow sorry guys I figured it out right after I posted this question. The problem is the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints needed to be set to YES

Comment: Not sure where you are creating this but occasionally you need to put layout code in viewDidLayoutSubviews:.  This way when you are setting the frame you can be sure it's the right size.

Comment: If you're no longer having the issue, consider closing/deleting your question.

Comment: Answer this question yourself and mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem! The only thing that I had to do was set `_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to yes and then adjust the auto layout code to work with it.